# How to enclose a regex inside an if-else condition? [Please read description]

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I am extracting the available balance (in Indian Rupees) from text messages using this regex

```
(?s)(?i).*(?:avbl|a\/c|available|avl|acct|account|)\\s+(?:balance|bal)\\s*(?::|\\-|\\=|is|\\-|)\\s*(?:Rs?|INR|)(?:[\\s.]*)(?P<balance>[0-9,]+(?:.[0-9]+)?|.[0-9]+)
```

But there are some messages without balance and this throws error in those cases. Is there a way to put the above regex inside an if else condition? Like, if this pattern is found, get the group 'balance' = <balance_amount> otherwise 'balance' = None?

I have tried enclosing the above regex in an if-else condition but the balance just comes as None

```
(?s)(?i).((?:avbl|a\/c|available|avl|acct|account|)\\s+(?:balance|bal)\\s*(?::|\\-|\\=|is|\\-|)\\s*(?:Rs?|INR|)(?:[\\s.]*)(?P<balance>[0-9,]+(?:.[0-9]+)?|.[0-9]+)|)
```

Please help

Comment: Which python method are you using to match the regex with the text message?  Most re.find, re.match, etc all return None if no match is found.  Can you just check for that None and handle it appropriately?

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to ask? You said you want the regex to match `None` but after that you said that you tried and it matched `None`. please clarify your question. in general, if you want something to be matched but can be found or not use `?`. for example: the regex `che?at` will match `cheat` as long as `chat`

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

words = 'xblue'
words2 = 'green'
def foo(text):
    test = re.compile('blue')
    match = test.search(text)
    if match == None:
        return ''
    else:
        return match.group()
print(foo(words2))
print(foo(words))
```

will print
"

blue
"

As Frank said in the comments, you could just write it in an if function to return what you want.
There is probably a way to match a no-length string once using built-in regex if statements and/or lookahead, but that would also make the regex even longer and harder to read.